# what is the difference between these salting methods

Tags: java

```
  // Salt
    byte[] salt = {
    (byte)0xc7, (byte)0x73, (byte)0x21, (byte)0x8c,
    (byte)0x7e, (byte)0xc8, (byte)0xee, (byte)0x99
    };
```

and

```
// salt
byte salt[] = {
    -87, -101, -56, 50, 86, 53, -29, 3
};
```

how can I convert the first piece of code tp look like the second. My java is very liitle

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference.

You are only initialize the instance salt, which type is array of bytes. Java does not have memory of "how I got these numbers in the array" (it does not need one).

After initialization, you have in both cases a variable salt with some numbers in its array. No more, no less.